# System.InvalidCastException when calling a class which extends application

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, android-activity, casting

I am working on an Android c# app where I have an class extends from `Application` called `MyApplication`. Inside `MyApplication` file, I have this method called `getDataFromDB()`. I am trying to call this method from my `Activity` but I am getting this exception during runtime:

> System.InvalidCastException:

**MyApplication.cs**

```
public class MyApplication : Application
{
    public MyApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownerShip) : base(handle, ownerShip)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        getDataFromDB();
    }

    public void getDataFromDB()
    { // code
    }
 }
```

**Activity.cs**

```
MyApplication application = ((MyApplication)this.ApplicationContext); //here's the location of the exception
application.getDataFromDB();
```

I don't have a clue why this exception is thrown. It doesn't seems to me that my casting is wrong. Would you please help me ?

Comment: `InvalidCastException` means for sure something wrong with casting. Did you tried checking runtime type of `this.ApplicationContext` via some debugger say

Comment: The `ApplicationContext` is not necessarily the `Application` instance.

Comment: @TKK So what do I need to write ? I have tried `MyApplication application = ((MyApplication)this.Application);` but also I am getting an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it out by removing the Arguments of the contructor of `MyApplication` like that:

```
 public class MyApplication : Application
{
public MyApplication() : base(handle, ownerShip) //here's the editing location
{
}

public override void OnCreate()
{
    base.OnCreate();

    getDataFromDB();
}

public void getDataFromDB()
{ // code
}
}
```

Then I called the `Application`:

```
MyApplication application = new MyApplication();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ApplicationContext` is not necessarily the same object as the `Application` instance. I've seen this most often in emulators, but it can also be device specific.

In a Java app, you could cast the object returned by [`Activity#getApplication()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication()). But according to a [post on the Xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44999/android-getapplication), an equivalent method does not exist in Xamarin. Instead, you can cast the `Application` property:

```
MyApplication app = (MyApplication) Application;
```

I'm not sure when the property is set, so this may not work in a field initializer.

Another option is to have `MyApplication` save a static reference to itself in `OnCreate()`, and provide a static getter. Although static fields are usually evil, this works because the `Application` instance is effectively a singleton, and its `OnCreate` will be called before any other component is created. The static reference can't leak the application because the application already has the same lifetime as the process.